# how can I fix resizing iamge problem in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, xampp, elementor

error :The server does not have ImageMagick or GD installed and/or enabled! Any of these libraries are required for WordPress to be able to resize images. Please contact your server administrator to enable this before continuing.

please tell me if you know this problem

Comment: You need to install ImageMagick to support resizing in Word Press. See https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php

Answer (score 3):

1. Open xampp control panel.
2. Start apache and mysql.
3. Click on config option of apache.
4. Click on php.ini and open it.
5. Press Ctrl+F and search "extension=" or "extension=fileinfo".
6. On the next line to "extension=fileinfo", add "extension=gd".
7. Save the file.
8. Stop apache and restart it.

Comment: That did it for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

in some cases there is "extension=gd" already given. but commented with a ";". You need the romove the ";" to uncomment it. Then your problem should be solved.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).